# in one of my app i integrated google map and play-console is warn me about some GCP API KEY

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-console

i have integrated google map and this below function is google warn me about.

```
    Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(REQUEST_URL);
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("location", QueryUtil.locationParam);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("rankby", "distance");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("type", place);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("name", place);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("key", API_KEY);
    return new CafeListLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString(), favouriteDB);
```

And below pic is the warning from Google.

[image: Google playconsole warning]

Comment: is your `API_KEY` restricted with sha-1 in Google api console ?

Comment: i don't know ..maybe yes.. lemme check @KuLdipPaTel